# Input of a transaction

Tags: transactions, transaction-input

If i want to send 0.2 bitcoin to Bob, will my transaction (in the input field) contain the list of all my previous transactions (both the ones in which i received bitcoins and the ones in which i sent bitcoins) ?

Answer (score 3):

Probably no.

Bitcoin transactions work by consuming transaction outputs and creating new transaction outputs. Your wallet will look at what outputs it has available to spend (i.e. your received coins) and choose enough outputs to cover the amount that you want to send plus the transaction fee. If you have sent Bitcoin before, then not all of the outputs that  you have received will be eligible for selection because some of them have already been spent. Your wallet will also choose enough outputs, not all of them, unless all of them are needed to be enough.

So in general, your transaction does not contain a list of all of your previous transactions. The only case where it might is if your wallet decides it needs all available transaction outputs to cover the amount you are sending. And even then, if you have sent Bitcoin before, then some will not be part of the inputs list as they would already be spent.